# weka nominal attribute cannot have duplicate labels

Tags: attributes, duplicates, label, weka

I am really new to Weka.

I want to train and test my data through Weka, 
but I have problem with opening the file before preprocess.
It keeps sending error message with attribute name..

[nominal attribute duplicate labels error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vo6if.jpg)

In my arff file, there is

@ATTRIBUTE name {,3Buster,Aaro,...(skip)...,Alix,Allaster,**Alley,Alley Cat**,...}

and Weka keeps sending error message to duplicate name such as "John, John Graham" or "Aaron, Aaron Oliver".

Is it space is seen as another label in arff file?
I converted csv file directly to arff file, and that would be the problem?

I finally decided to change the name into binary class like {A, NA},
But I am so curious about this problem.

Thanks for reading :-)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same errors when trying to open a CSV file in Weka and also when converting it to ARFF format using the WekaViewer tool.

I solved it by removing the first column (the index column which doesn't have a header) in my file and the error was fixed!